# Powermock chained method calls in final class

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

when I mock a chained method call I get a nullpointer exception.

My code is looking like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Comment.class, CommentThread.class})
public class YoutubeTest {

@Test
public void testSortCommentsByDate() {
Comment youtubeCommentOne = PowerMockito.mock(Comment.class); // This is a final class

Mockito.when(youtubeCommentOne.getSnippet().getUpdatedAt().getValue()).thenReturn(youtubeCommentOneDate);

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting a chain method call should work:

```
Comment commentMock = PowerMockito.mock(Comment.class);
CommentThread commentThreadMock = PowerMockito.mock(CommentThread.class);

when(commentMock.getSnippet()).thenReturn(commentThreadMock);
when(commentThreadMock.getUpdatedAt()).thenReturn(new DateTime(youtubeCommentOneDate));
```

If it's not what you are looking for, check out [this](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/blob/62236dbbb76953158f3a28c0d3a04980f7b9d171/modules/module-test/mockito/junit4/src/test/java/samples/powermockito/junit4/annotationbased/MockFinalUsingAnnotationsWithAnswersTest.java) example. 
According to this, returning deep stubs should solve the problem.

Try to mock Comment object using Mockito annotation:

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) 
Comment youtubeCommentOne;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was exactly my problem.